# Comparação __FILE__ e $0

Tags: ruby, arquivo

Recentemente vi essa tomada de decisão em um código ruby:

```
if __FILE__ == $0

    ....
```

Então mandei imprimir `__FILE__` e `$0` separadamente no irb e vi que os dois passam a mesma informação, minhas dúvidas são:

- Por que (quando) fazer essa comparação?
- Por que não comparar com o mesmo comando (`__FILE__ == __FILE__`)?
- Tem algum método para obter o nome do arquivo diretamente pelo `__FILE__` sem que tenha de filtrar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No [ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/) tem um boa explicação sobre o que/porque. Veja:

> `__ FILE__` é a variável mágica que contém o nome do arquivo atual. `$0` é o nome do arquivo usado para iniciar o programa. Basicamente verifica-se
>   "Se este é o arquivo principal que está sendo usado ..." Isso permite
>   que um arquivo seja usado como uma biblioteca, e não para executar
>   o código nesse contexto, mas se o arquivo está sendo usado como um
>   executável, execute esse código.

Veja mais detalhes aqui [neste artigo](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/)<sup>(en)</sup>.